# Invalid asm.js: Unexpected token in react build app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-chrome, firefox

After build react app I'm getting warnings in chrome:

> Invalid asm.js: Unexpected token

and firefox:

> asm.js type error: Disabled by debugger

And I can't understand where it comes from.

My app use firebase as backend.

Comment: Could you try running your app incognito?

Comment: @Romanas did you find a solution for this?